# Getting value using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html

Hello i am writing a calculator in PHP and php is working fine, Now what i want is to get value from users.

Im not sure what im missing or i have to use any JS file to do it. I have inbuilt value set `$v = 1000000;` but i want user to set value as per there need. Also want inbuild remain for defualt user. I think im not using correct way for form.

html

```
<form action="index.php" method="Get">
Value: <input type="text" name="v" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

php

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$v = 1000000;
do {
    $i++;
    $pay  = round($v + $i);
    echo "<tr><td><b>Value</b> $" . number_format($v) . "</td><tr>";
    $v = $v + $bid;
} while ($i <= 5);
?>
```

I have modified and hide my other personal codes :)

**fixed:** `$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (int)$_GET['v'] : 1000000;`

Thanks in advance
live : http://ffsng.deewayz.in/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your form uses `$_GET` you have to assign that to your `$v` variable, but with condition, if `isset`.

Change:

```
$v = 1000000;
```

to:

```
$v = isset($_GET['v']) ? (int)$_GET['v'] : 1000000;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get the value back from the form on the reload like this:

```
$v = $_GET['v'];
```

Otherwise the GET value is simply not used in your code.

Mihai correctly points out that if a form value isn't set, you will get an error if your code tries to use is, so run with the test first.

Comment: @DeepakKumar They are really the same thing, except Mihai introduced a test to see if it is passed, if not, it assigns a default value, otherwise it uses the value sent. Use his code (it is a more thorough code sample than mine - which really only addressed the fact that you were not doing anything with the GET data).

Comment: Yes i understood thanks so much for solving out my question. very thankfull to you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
    <?php
$i = 0;
$v =$_GET['v'];
do {
    $i++;
    $pay  = round($v + $i);
    echo "<tr><td><b>Value</b> $" . number_format($v) . "</td><tr>";
    $v = $v + $bid;
} while ($i <= 5);
?>
```